# Como juntar textos em uma textbox arrastando eles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tenho uma textbox vazia, e tenho alguns botões com valores como:

`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `palavra1`, `palavra2`

assim por diante.

Quero preencher esse textbox arrastando esses botoes para dentro dele, não apenas clicando neles, vi algo que pode ser feito no HTML5/Javascript, mas não consegui solucionar.

Obs: Eu Clicaria e segurando o mouse arrastaria esse botão para dentro da textbox e a textbox pegaria o valor desse botão, como se fosse um verdadeiro lego montando dentro da textbox as strings.

Obs 2: Tem que ser com botões ou inputs, não com imagens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso pode ser resolvido utilizando html e javascript.

O seu html ficaria assim:

```js
  function allowDrop(ev)
        {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }

        function drag(ev)
        {
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
        }

        function drop(ev)
        {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
            ev.target.innerHTML+=" <p>"+document.getElementById(data).innerHTML+"</p>";
            
        }
```

```css
.div 
        {
            width:350px;height:70px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
        }
```

```html
<div class="div" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div class="div" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <button id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">Code</button>
    <button id="drag2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">Code</button>
</div>
```

Pode rodar para testar, acho que esta solução atende perfeitamente você.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, eu rodei aqui, mas por algum motivo, eu tento arrastar o botão para essa div, e ele não pega o valor e não realiza nada, testei no meu projeto e também não rodou.

Comment: coloca seu codigo inteira que ae tentamos fazer rodar, como ele em sites de javascript online, ex: jsfiddle.net

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9kx6zvva/

Comment: coloquei da forma mais simplificada possivel o que procuro, coloquei textarea mas pode ser até uma div, so não mando todo codigo pelo tamanho dele ..

Comment: Este arquivo me enviou esta sem o js

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zft0tpos/ atualizado

Comment: Você esta usando inputs normais e não botões, tente pegar o exemplo e alterar.

Comment: eu utilizei o próprio exemplo seu,  e não funcionou aqui, porem achei outros exemplos parecidos e também não rodaram muito bem, acredito que o problema esteja na minha maquina, porem sua resposta está correta de certa forma.

Comment: achei o problema, era meu mouse que não selecionava kk, muito obrigado pela paciencia, topico solucionado.